# Insert row based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am new to macro Excel functions and I am trying to insert a row when there is a change in the cell value of a particular column. For example,

```html
row_no       B     
1            p
2            p
3            p
4            q
5            q
6            q
7            q
```

A row should be inserted at row 3 as the value in column 1 has changed. Do you have any ideas?

Right now, this is my code.

```html
  Sub MySub()
  Do While B1 <> B2
    CurrentSheet.Range("a1:i1").EntireRow.Insert
  Loop
  End Sub
```

It is still not working, do all of you have any idea why?

Comment: Learn how to write loops in VBA and how to loop through ranges of cells. Also google how to insert a row using VBA. Good luck.

Comment: @AndreTerra Hi, I have tried looping and there is no error after running the above edited code in excel but it is still not working, do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'set you data sheet here
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  'get the last row in column A
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1    'loop from last row to row 2
        If ws.Range("A" & i) <> ws.Range("A" & i - 1) Then  'compare value if not same
            ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert  'if value are not same insert row
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just another question, when a row is inserted, do you have any idea how to make some cells of the inserted have the value of 0?

Comment: @Faheera - Something like `ws.Range("col_name" & i +1)` should work, however depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following into your **Sheet1 (Sheet1)** VBA module (Or the module that pertains to the worksheet you want this functionality in)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This inserts a row below the changed cell if that cell's column number is column 1 or **A**